# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left[x\right]+\left[y\right]+\left[z\right]\right)\,dxdydz$

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

**Question**

For a real number $x$,Then

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left[x\right]+\left[y\right]+\left[z\right]\right)dxdydz$

$[$ $]=$greatest integer function

[image]

**MY approach**

MY first thought is that answer can be $0$, because
limit is $0$ to $1$. But it is wrong at the same time because at $(1,1,1)$, grt function will not give $0$

I tried to apply
 [Dirichlet Triple Integral Theorem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY--LngpTZAhUFOY8KHV9KBIkQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrilliant.org%2Fprofile%2Fsteven-b7sfdv%2Fsets%2Fproof-problems%2F135287%2Fdirichlet-triple-integral%2F&usg=AOvVaw0_qe6ZS4dFjukSuvKW8TKC)
But it does not Fit here properly

**Based ON all comments**

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left[x\right]+\left[y\right]+\left[z\right]\right)$dxdydz=
3$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}$dxdydz=3

Comment: Your initial thinking is correct. The integrand is non-zero only on a set of measure zero in the region of integration, so it doesn't affect the value of the integral. Think of it as an integral with all the upper limits tending to $1$ from the left side of the real line.

Comment: $\lceil x\rceil$ = 1 for $0 < x \leq 1$ right ? Same for $y$ and $z$. So for the simple case $\int_{0+\epsilon}^1 \lceil x \rceil dx =  \int_{0}^1 \lceil x \rceil dx = 1$.

Comment: Edit: Your posted image shows the ceiling function, not the floor function. So, your integral basically evaluates to $3$

Comment: Oh, wait, in the problem, it is $\lceil\cdot\rceil$, which is **not** the greatest integer function, it is the smallest integer greater than or equal $x$.

Comment: The integral you typed is different from the integral in the picture.

Comment: Why did you delete the image? The image made clear you might have misread the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \lceil 
 x \rceil  + \lceil y\rceil + \lceil z\rceil dxdydz=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} 3 dxdydz=3.$$

Note that on the interior of the region of integration the integrand $$\lceil 
 x \rceil  + \lceil y\rceil + \lceil z\rceil =3$$

Thus the value of the integral is the volume of the region times $3$.

Comment: Hello can you confirm, had it been the floor function instead of the ceil, the integrand would have been 0 and hence the whole integral would be zero aswell?

Comment: yes, I agree that if the integrand were  the sum of floor functions, the integral would have been zero instead.